# Encode php multidimensional arrays to json

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode

I have a problem when try to encode multidimensional array to json.
How to remove key "0" and "1"?'

This is my code

```
$ch_name = count($app->request->post('ch_name'));
        for ($i=0; $i < $ch_name; $i++) {
            $min = count($app->request->post('minim_channel_'.$i));
            for ($j=$min - 1; $j >= 0; $j--) { 
                $gros[$j] = array('min' =>$app->request->post('minim_channel_'.$i)[$j], 'price' => $app->request->post('harga_channel_'.$i)[$j]);
            }
            $prices[$i] = array('channel' => $app->request->post('ch_name')[$i], 'price' => $app->request->post('harsat_channel_'.$i), 'grosir' => array($gros));
        }

        echo json_encode($prices);
```

and this is the result

```
[{"channel":"Tokopedia","price":"10000","grosir":[{"1":{"min":"3","price":"9500"},"0":{"min":"10","price":"9000"}}]},{"channel":"Lapak","price":"10500","grosir":[{"1":{"min":"3","price":"9700"},"0":{"min":"10","price":"9200"}}]}]
```

Comment: Do you mean remove the keys (1 and 0) in this bit? "grosir":[{"1":{"min":"3","price":"9700"},"0":{"min":"10","price":"9200"}}

Comment: try changing `$gros[$j]` to `$gros[]` and `$prices[$i]` to `$prices[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing the following part of your code

```
for ($j=$min - 1; $j >= 0; $j--) { 
    $gros[$j] = array('min' =>$app->request->post('minim_channel_'.$i)[$j], 'price' => $app->request->post('harga_channel_'.$i)[$j]);
}
```

to

```
$gros = array();
for ($j=$min - 1; $j >= 0; $j--) { 
    $gros[] = array('min' =>$app->request->post('minim_channel_'.$i)[$j], 'price' => $app->request->post('harga_channel_'.$i)[$j]);
}
```

and see if that does what you want it to do.